# Saving data by grails domain without id

Tags: grails

I have domain class,in which I am declaring id as string and in mapping id is mapped to ROWID.I do not want that id to take part in insert operation.
But,while persisting through domain,I am getting the error like :
    null id in com.bt.viewer.TCircuitDetails entry
Can anybody help regarding:do I need to mention database column for id?
In gorm query that insertion sql is generating hibernate sequence for id,which I can not use
for any of the column.

I can assign id to one primary key column which is there in database,but id is taking only hibernate sequence,so I can not map id to any of the column.I can not alter table with addition of new column to accomodate id value.

What is the solution.Please help

Thanks..

Comment: Just to clarify: you are trying to generate your own values for an `id` column and don't want Hibernate to generate its own id under any name at all?

Comment: Yes.I want to insert some alpha numeric value to id column,not the hibernate sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override Hibernate's default identity generator - [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#identity) is the relevant chapter in the Grails documentation which basically points you to Hibernate documentation.

From what I gather you would need to implement a custom `IdentifierGenerator` similarly to how [this](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1003607) person did it for their project.

I don't know why you are trying to define your own IDs but perhaps the following simpler solution would work for you as well: let Grails/Hibernate store its ID into another column (say `hibernate_id`) and then you can use `id` for your own purposes by inserting `id column: 'hibernate_id'` into the `mapping` block (see the link to Grails documentation). You would need to use `DomainClass.findById()` instead of `DomainClass.get()` everywhere, though.